# C++ language design: child calls all virtual ancestor constructors

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, language-design

This question's content hinges upon my understanding of how virtual inheritance works in C++. Correct me if any of this is wrong.

In C++, virtual inheritance requires (either implicit or explicit) calls to the constructors of all ancestor classes in a subclass, which also prevents any ancestor from calling another ancestor's constructor. In other words:

```
class Grandparent{
public:
    Grandparent(string const& message) { 
        std::cerr << "Grandparent says " << message << '\n';
    }
};

class Parent : virtual Grandparent{
public:
    Parent(string const& message)
        : Grandparent(string("hello parent. Parent says ") + message)
    {}
}

class Child : virtual Parent{
public:
    Child(void)
        : Grandparent(""), // Required, since Grandparent has no default ctor
          Parent("hello child. Child says are we there yet"?)
    {}
}
```

In this example, constructing an instance of `Child` should simply print out "Grandparent says\n" to standard error, since the `Parent` constructor's call to the `Grandparent` constructor gets removed. In other words, the "effective" `Parent` constructor that gets executed by the child looks like this:

```
Parent(string const& message) {}
```

But this seems counterintuitive and problematic. Why should the child class have to explicitly call the grandparent's constructor when the parent already does that? I'm aware of the [diamond problem](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/multiple-inheritance-in-c-and-the-diamond-problem-7c12a9ddbbec), it doesn't apply here because the child class has only one direct parent. The language guarantees that the parent already calls its grandparent's constructor, so why should this task be delegated to the child?

Furthermore, the erasure of the parent's calls to the grandparent constructor hinders the effectiveness of inheritance. The child must duplicate some of the parent's initialization code if it wants to truly inherit the parent's behavior. For example:

```
Parent::Parent(string const& msg)
    : Grandparent(some_parent_logic(msg))
    {}
Child::Child(string const& msg)
    : Parent("doesn't matter anymore"),
      GrandParent(some_child_logic(some_parent_logic(msg))) // Can't inherit implicit use of parent logic
```

This isn't a huge problem if you don't use complicated logic when making calls to ancestor constructors, but the redundancy problem tends to grow as the inheritance chain grows longer. And it seems a tad blasphemous (from an OO perspective) for the child to be required to manually address all of its ancestors when only inheriting directly from one of them.

I suppose what I'm asking at the end of the day is:

1. Is there any reason the language can't delegate ancestor initialization to the parent when there is only one parent?
2. Why doesn't the language allow delegation of ancestor constructors? e.g. `Child::Child(void): Parent1(), Parent2() {}` causes `Parent1` to initialize `Grandparent`, while `Child::Child(void): Parent2(), Parent1() {}` causes `Parent2` to initialize `Grandparent`, while `Child::Child(void): Grandparent("The child overrides."), Parent1(), Parent2()` explicitly initializes `Grandparent`.
3. Are there any plans floating around the Standards Committee regarding changes to C++ virtual inheritance in future versions?

Comment: If you have no diamond, you do not need virtual inheritance. If you do not need it, you should not wonder, why it behaves different in a way which makes no sense in the abuse case. To keeps the things "simple", the language give the simple rule that the outermost constructor must construct the virtual bases. Every other rule I can think about makes live much much more complicated. I can't think about any "automated" order which will work in all use cases.

Comment: I believe virtual inheritance is necessary for runtime polymorphism. Or does virtual only need to be applied to individual methods in order to obtain this?

Comment: BINGO! You got it. virtual inheritance is only needed to suppress to get multiple instances of base classes if multiple base classes derive from same class. virtual methods have nothing to do with virtual inheritance...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the language designers could have done better (honestly, I have only found a couple cases where virtual inheritance made sense in 15 years of c++ development), but the rule we have simply requires that the most derived class construct the virtually inherited base. It does make some sense in that it is only when the most-derived type is constructed that we actually know where the virtual base is going to 'live'.

Any rule that a type other than the most-derived would construct the virtual base would make an already complicated business quite a bit more so.